# OpenCL: clSetKernelArg vs. clSetKernelArg + clEnqueueWriteBuffer

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

A question regarding buffer transfer in OpenCL:
I want to pass a buffer (cl_mem) from the host to the kernel (i.e. to the device).
There are two host-functions:

- clEnqueueWriteBuffer
- clSetKernelArg

I use clSetKernelArg to pass my buffer to one of the kernel arguments. But does this mean that the buffer is automatically transfered to the device?
Further, there is the function clEnqueueWriteBuffer which writes a buffer to a device.

My question: is there any difference in using (a.) only clSetKernelArg or (b.) clSetKernelArg and clEnqueueWriteBuffer in combination for my use-case (pass buffers to kernel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call both functions before enqueuing a kernel for execution.

> **clSetKernelArg**
>
> Used to set the argument value for a specific argument of a kernel.

This one only sets the argument **value**, e.g. some pointer, for the called kernel. There are **no implicit data transfers**.

---

Think of the following examples:

- the same memory object is used as argument for different kernels

  - =>  only one write to device needed; but multiple arguments to be set for different kernels
- a changing input memory object could be used multiple times with the same kernel

  - => one write per call; but kernel argument only set once
- a read and a write buffer might be switched using `clSetKernelArg()` between two calls of the same kernel (double buffering)

  - => maybe no transfer, or only every n iterations; but two arguments set before every call

**In general:** Data transfers between host and compute device are very expensive, and hence should be avoided, which is best possible by explicitly triggering them.

- https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html
- https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueWriteBuffer.html

Comment: thanks. But why does it (in my test programs) also work when I only use clSetKernelArg? Is the data than copied from the host to the device on-demand, i.e. when accessing the buffer in the kernel?

Comment: Depending on your [clCreateBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html), you might have already initialised the memory object from host memory, e.g. via `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`.